# Disabling Django's automatic assignment of backwards relations of unsaved objects

Tags: python, django

I have two instances of objects saved in the database:

```
class Object:
    pass

class Temporary:
    relation = OneToOneField(Object, related_name='temporary')


obj = Object.objects.create()
the_only_correct_temp = Temporary.objects.create(relation=obj)
```

Now I want to perform some calculations using additional Temporary objects, which will never be saved to the db, yet are crucial for those calculations. So I create them:

```
temp1 = Temporary(relation=obj)
temp2 = Temporary(relation=obj)
```

Please note that I never save them. Now, after executing the code above, `obj.temporary` is equal to `temp2`, even though it has a different object assigned in the database (`the_only_correct_temp`), and I never explicitly assigned `temp2` to it. This is happening, because Django somehow follows the relation when creating `temp2`, and implicitly sets the attribute on `obj`. I know I can "restore" the correct state by calling

```
obj = Object.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
```

But this is a performance hit. I could also pass the copy of `obj` when creating `temp1` and `temp2`, but copying is expensive too.

So the question is: how can I prevent Django (1.11) from assigning **unsaved** instances of `Temporary` to the `obj.temporary` field?

Comment: Don't use a Django model if you don't want stuff to go to the DB. Use a `RealTemporary` class that has the same fields & methods as `Temporary` but is not a Django model. Depending on the case you might want to have, say, `Temporary` inherit from `RealTemporary` to be more DRY...

Comment: @Bakuriu Interesting approach. Now I'm not yet convinced that I like the idea of splitting it into two classes just because Django decided to be annoying. So I'm still hoping there could exist some magic switch to disable it.. But feel free to post it as an answer!